No system default bubble notification UI when copying data in Android 13 and later (Samsung, Xiaomi)
According to official documentation:

Starting in Android 13, the system displays a standard visual confirmation when content is added to the clipboard.


But in reality, some devices lack default UI feedback (e.g. Samsung, Xiaomi), and they are already in Android 13 & 14.
Is there any way to check this condition and fallback to our own visual feedback?
